How to create a drop in serializer replacement for Django ReadOnlyViewSet that is very fast?
I've noticed that Django Serializers are extremely slow even after N+1 type problems (I think). I'm basing that off my own experience and questions such as these

ModelSerializer is extremely slow in Django REST framework
https://hakibenita.com/django-rest-framework-slow

In my case I have a model for users
from django.contrib.auth.models
from rest_framework.viewsets import ReadOnlyModelViewSet

class UserViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filterset_fields = {'groups__name': ['exact', 'in']

If I have a function like the following:
def serialize_user_only_fields_I_care(user_instance):
    return {
        'name': user_instance.first_name,
        'last_name': user_instance.last_name,
        'username': user_instance.username,
    }

how do I write a custom serializer class so I can use it as serializer_class = MyUserSerializer and it skips validation etc. I expect since it's readonly validation also doesn't make as much sense but maybe I'm missing something.

Share the UserSerializer...

return {f: getattr(user_instance, f) for f in user_instance._meta.fields} is a severe security risk, since it impliclty says "all fields". It also makes not much sense: some fields don't make to a JSON serializable type, so the rendering of the serialized data will fail.

pointed taken re security I edited - that was a toy example but think best to not show "bad practices in examples" and the point is i only want 3 fields or smth like that rather than "everything".

You can override the .to_representation(…) [drf-doc] to serialize data to a "primtive" representation, so:
from rest_framework.serializers import BaseSerializer


class SimpleReadonlySerializer(BaseSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return {field: getattr(instance, field) for field in self.Meta.fields}
and thus work with:
class MyUserSerializer(SimpleReadonlySerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['username', 'email']
I would strongly advise not to just retrieve all fields and serialize these. First of all this can be a severe security vulnerability since you are in this case exposing (hashed) passwords. But more importantly, not all fields boil down to primitive types, for example with ForeignKeys, ManyToManyFields, etc.
